# Execute function after cache timeout

Tags: django, caching, triggers

Scenario: I use Local-memory caching: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching. I cached some data in local memory. And the timeout of it depends on something else (It mean I don't know exactly timeout).
But I want to run some code after this cache timeout.
Question: Are django have event or trigger for cache timeout?

Comment: By default, its set to 300 seconds, unless you override the settings. Details can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-CACHES-TIMEOUT)

Comment: You are going to cache whole view ? using @cache_page (decorator) ?

Comment: Provide us information what you are using ? LocMemCache, FileBasedCache, DatabaseCache ?

Comment: No no, I want to catch the time which cache timeout. To call other method.
I using local memmory cache